# What is it wrong with my captcha validator in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, captcha

This is my rule from the model:

```
array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction'=>'site/captcha', 'message'=>'Captcha invalid!','allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements())
```

and in the controller I have this:

```
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($model->validate()); echo "</pre>";
```

The result of the var_dump it is always false.

Comment: Please check this link :- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11425-solved-ccaptcha-doesnt-seems-to-work-on-cactiveform/ . hope your problem will solved.

Comment: I tried every posibility, but I got two part.  The first part, always validate, or always NOT validate

Comment: Can you give some idea, that i should try ?

Answer (score 0):

If `$model->validate()` return false, this means validation of **one or more fields** failed. `verifyCode` is **one** of the model's fields, and the model have some other fields in addition to `verifyCode`. So, you should check validation of other fields too. I think your problem isn't related to captcha. Probably some other fields are incorrect. Also, `$model->validate()` just show you `true`  or `false`, and you can't understand what fields have validation error. So it's better to use `var_dump($model->getErrors())` for see validation errors.